# Adding Biography to a LaTex article

Tags: article

I have been trying to add my biography to a `.tex` file with `\documentclass{article}`. Is there a way to do that? Should I use a package for that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}} \author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract} The abstract text goes here. \end{abstract}

\section{Introduction} Here is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here} Write your subsection text here.

\section{Conclusion} Write your conclusion here.

\end{document}

\begin{biography} Author 1 Bio \end{biography}

\begin{biography} Author 2 Bio \end{biography}
```

Comment: You can manually enter your bibliography, but a more powerful and flexible option is to use a bibtex database. I'd recommend using biblatex. See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex

Comment: @penguinpreferred, biography `\neq` bibliography. I believe the OP is asking about adding a "biographical sketch" of sorts.

Comment: Depending on what you want the biography to look like, it should be pretty straight forward using a tabular or a description list. Can you give a hint on the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Anything after `\end{document}` will be ignored.  In many case just using a standard `flushleft` or `flushright` enviornment, perhaps with a small font size, will be sufficient.  Some documentclasses provide specific environments for biographies, but there is not one in `article`

Comment: @Johannes_B, I am expecting to see Biographies of the authors at the end of the article. This is the second document I prepared by using LaTex, therefore I am not familiar to some things in LaTex. Thank you..

Comment: @Andrew, I will try to implement your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `wrapfig` package. The following is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{25mm} 
    \includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
  \end{wrapfigure}\par
  \textbf{Author A} is a well-known author in the field of the journal scope. His/Her research interests include interest 1, interest 2.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find https://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins better, I've given a full description as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility might be to use the `description` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}} \author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract} The abstract text goes here. \end{abstract}

\section{Introduction} Here is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here} Write your subsection text here.

\section{Conclusion} Write your conclusion here.

\section*{Authors}

\begin{description}
    \item[Santa Claus] is a world-renowned expert on the psychology of giving and author of \emph{How to Raise Your Reindeer}.
    \item[The Tooth Fairy] has published widely on the commodification of children's body parts and the commercialisation of human imaginative capacities.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: descriptive biographies]

Answer (score 3):

This is just one way; I have seen it done many different ways.

The `\subsection*{}` commands could be commented out if you prefer that look better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}} 
\author{Author's Name}

\begin{document}    
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} 
  The abstract text goes here. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction} 
Here is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here} 
Write your subsection text here.

\section{Conclusion} 
Write your conclusion here.

\section*{Authors' Biographies}
\subsection*{Author One}
\textbf{Author One} is an extraordinary researcher powered by caffeine and Red Bull.
He has written several incredible articles that will change your life forever.

\subsection*{Author Two}
\textbf{Author Two} is the Chief Duck Researcher at the National Wildlife Federation.
He has contributed to extensive research studying the migration patterns of duck 
species all over the globe.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following from [sisay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/62373/sisay-chala), if you want to include a picture, then use [picins](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins) and the following:

```
\section*{Author biographies}
\parpic{\includegraphics[width=1in,clip,keepaspectratio]{headshot.jpg}}
\noindent {\bf Author Name} is the most famous author in her field. 
She is particularly interested in X and Y, and also dabbles in Z.
```